# how to sum three field in same table in mysql

Tags: sql, union, sum

I have a table which has fields and I want to sum data from three different fields like below. I made the code as follow, but have error. So please help me to make correct code to me :

```
    <?php include "config.php"; ?> 
    <?php $results = mysql_query
("SELECT sum(hit),as total from ( 
select hit from sound union 
select hit from soundK union 
select hit from soundD ") ; 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) 
{ ?> 
<?php echo $row[total];?> <?php }?>
```

so please help as soon as possible

thanks in advance

Comment: give your database structure.. because you need to map one table to other using joins.. so you need foreign key

Comment: That's not three different fields in the same table, it the same field name from three different tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have a extra `,`,  missing a closing `)` and a derived table alias:

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?> 
<?php $results = mysql_query(
    "SELECT sum(hit) as total 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT sum(hit) hit from sound 
        UNION ALL SELECT sum(hit) hit from soundK 
        UNION ALL SELECT sum(hit) hit from soundD 
    ) rs") ; 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) { ?> 
    <?php echo $row['total'];?>
<?php }?>
```

If you want 3 individual columns:

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?> 
<?php $results = mysql_query(
    "SELECT soundHits, soundKHits, soundDHits
    FROM ( 
        SELECT sum(hit) soundHits from sound
    ) a, (
        SELECT sum(hit) soundKHits from soundK
    ) b, ( 
        SELECT sum(hit) soundDHits from soundD 
    ) c") ; 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) { ?> 
    soundHits: <?php echo $row['soundHits'] ;?>
    soundKHits: <?php echo $row['soundKHits'] ;?>
    soundDHits: <?php echo $row['soundDHits'] ;?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: But wouldn't this generate only one sum ??
and not sum for each row's three colomn ?

Comment: @gaurav-shah Ya, i believe that is what the OP wants.

Comment: I think the other way. anyways his question isn't clear enough.. so we can leave it to him to reply :)

Comment: but the two code you mentiond here is display error
on line
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) { ?> 

and for more details

I want to sum data as result of three fields (hit) frm sound + soundK + soundD
for example :

if hit from sound = 11
if hit from soundD= 22
if hit from soundK= 33

then I want total of them = 66

that I mean

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or ...

```
select (
    (select sum(hit) from sound) +
    (select sum(hit) from soundK) +
    (select sum(hit) from soundD))
```

Comment: You should wrap the inner selects with a `IFNULL()`, in case a table doesn't have any records.